# Run multiple Wget commands simultaneously

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing, wget

I have a text file that has a url and the desired file name on each line (seperated by a space). I am looping through this text file and downloading the url and saving it as the desired name using wget:

```
while IFS=' ' read a b
 do wget $a -O $b
done < list.txt
```

The problem is my list contains almost 9000 files so downloading them one by one will take a long time. Is there anyway I can download them simultaneously?

Comment: * do wget $a -O $b & *?

Comment: a google search on `bash limit number of background jobs` brings up several hits like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1537956), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38774355), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38160), [this](https://superuser.com/q/153630), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64694448) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49740746); several approaches addressed in the various answers ... some of them should work for this scenario

Comment: BTW, on systems with GNU tools, `xargs -P` is your friend.

Comment: `xargs -a list.txt -n 2 -P 4 -I{} wget "{}" -O "{}"`

Comment: @LéaGris I am not sure this code seperates the url from the filename as I get an error saying that the file was not found because it had just combined each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
number=10
while IFS=' ' read a b; do 
    if  test $(jobs | grep Running | wc -l) -ge $number; then
        sleep 1
    else
        echo "Starting $a..."
        wget $a -O $b &
    fi
done < list.txt
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```sh
while IFS=' ' read a b; do 
  wget $a -O $b &
done < list.txt

# Wait for background jobs to terminate...
wait
```

**PS:** Keep in mind that 9000 concurrent connections maybe not handled by the server, so I suggest you to limit the connection number in chunks.

Comment: I am not looking to do 9000 concurrent connections but maybe a small number like 10. How can I limit it to 10?

Comment: You can limit them by placing a counter into your loop. You have to code it on your own.